# valgrind error with strcpy: invalid read of size 1

Tags: c, memory, memory-management, malloc, valgrind

I am getting the following error:

```
Invalid read of size 1 at 0x4008F4: isNameValid (elections.c:76)
```

and it seems the error is caused by the `strcpy` function.
yet I don't know why is it wrong, since my code wouldn't run correctly without it. So how can I solve this?

a minimal example

```
bool isNameValid(const char *tribe_name) {
    char *str = malloc(sizeof (strlen(tribe_name) + 1));
    if (!str) {
        return false;
    }
    if (!strcpy(str, tribe_name)) {
        free(str);
        return false;
    }
}
```

PS: it works fine when `tribe_name` has less than 7 characters, but when I enter more than 7, I get the error above.

Comment: You asked this [one hour ago](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61593211/valgrind-error-with-strcpy-invalid-read-of-size) and it got closed and then deleted. Asking it again almost without changing anything doesn't really make things any different.

Comment: yes i deleted it because i wanted to add something

Comment: @MarcoBonelli Well, OP has changed the code a little bit! The `malloc(sizeof (strlen(tribe_name)+1))` is new - still wrong, but it's different.

Comment: yet someone closed it so i had to rewrite it

Comment: This should have been an edit to the original question. The edit would have submitted it for a re-open review.

Comment: @AdrianMole i wanted to edit it but it was already closed,, why is `malloc(sizeof (strlen(tribe_name)+1)) ` wrong?

Comment: Note: Editing a closed question is the correct thing to do, so that it then may be re-opened. Posting a new question like this is likely to have an impact on your ability to ask more questions.

Comment: `sizeof (strlen(tribe_name)+1)` <==> `sizeof(int)`

Comment: yes that solved the problem

Comment: @AdrianMole in my future questions i will pay attention to that , I am new to this website so i didn't know.

Comment: For future reference, when `valgrind` tells you that a C library function is responsible for an invalid memory operation, the problem is almost always that the _arguments_ to that function were somehow incorrect.  In this case, the allocation for `str` was the wrong size.

Answer (score 2):

```
char* str = malloc(sizeof (strlen(tribe_name) + 1));
```

`sizeof (strlen(tribe_name) + 1)` apparently evaluates to `sizeof(size_t)` in your case because `sizeof` yields the size in bytes of the object representation of the type of the expression and `sizeof(size_t)` is on modern 64-bit systems with 8 byte larger than `sizeof(int)` with 4 byte.

Since the return type of `strlen` is of type `size_t` and `1` is an `int` and per majority rule the `int` value will be promoted to `size_t` (the larger type) before the expression is evaluated, if `sizeof(size_t)` is larger than `sizeof(int)`, the result of `(strlen(tribe_name) + 1)` will be of type `size_t`.

So memory of the size of a `size_t` object with 8 bytes is allocated with that call to `malloc()`.

In 8 bytes you can only store a string of 7 characters plus the required string-terminating null character.

If you attempt to store a string of more than 7 characters in that memory, you will write beyond the bounds of the allocated memory, which is wrong.

---

Instead, It shall be

```
char* str = malloc(sizeof(char) * (strlen(tribe_name) + 1));
```

Comment: Actually, `sizeof (strlen(tribe_name) + 1)` evaluates to the larger of `sizeof(size_t)` and `sizeof(int)` because `strlen()` has a return type of `size_t`. If `size_t` is smaller than `int`, it is promoted to `int`, if it is larger, `1` is converted to `size_t`. I don't know what you mean by *per majority rule*.  `int` on 32-bit systems is only 4 bytes, not 8, but `size_t` has indeed 8 bytes on 64-bit systems.

Comment: @chqrlie Thanks for your input. Yes, you are right - I was confused . And since OP is only be able to store `7` characters, it should be `(sizeof(size_t) == 8) > (sizeof(int) == 4))` on his/her 64-bit system.

Answer (score 0):

You can save all that bother of making sure that you get the length of the character array correct by simply using `strdup`. Don't complicate matters unnecessarily!

Your code could simply be

```
bool isNameValid(const char *tribe_name) {
    char *str = strdup(tribe_name);
    if (!str) {
        return false;
    }
}
```